# Laptop keyboard - after cleaning some keys are connected to others

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Today my friend cleaned my laptop keyboard with some wet handkerchieves. He cleaned all the keys and also sides of the notebook.
Now there are some keys which are connected to others:
if I press "c" or the "." the result is "c." for both.
 Same story with "2" and "o", the result is "2o".
 Can this be caused by the humidity? How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Water & electricity are not the best bedfellows - see this for a scary story... http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely causes for this problem.

The first is you damaged a part of the layer which contains the conductive traces, so the wrong ones connect when the key is pressed. If this is the case, there is no easy way to replace this layer without replacing the keyboard, which you can likely find a replacement and instructions by searching for a replacement keyboard for your exact model of laptop.

The second cause is the internal ribbon connection became slightly dislodged when you were cleaning, resulting in the paths on the ribbon not quite lining up. Depending on which end of the ribbon, this could be easily solvable if it is the end where the ribbon connects to the motherboard, you would just remove and replace the keyboard. However, if the problem is at the end of the ribbon which connects inside the keyboard, laptop keyboards are usually not disassemblable and as such you would need to replace the keyboard.

Comment: You may want to reread the question and edit your answer accordingly. He mentions his friend did the cleaning. Now you make it sounds like its his own fault.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Neither of those happen unless you dismantle the keyboard, which the OP has not done.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that due to humidity, the keys' circuit wire got connected. Try keeping it in sunlight, that could remove the water from it.

Using water to clean an electronic device is not a good idea, you should use less wet cloth with surgical spirit or an alcohol/acetone related liquid. Those liquid evaporate very fast.